# HTML Display table to fit screen size

Tags: html, css, screen, fullscreen

I have a table of links for an image gallery that I want to be able to fit to the screen size if the window size is reduced. At the moment it just stays the same size.

```
<table class="images" id="albums">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a href="academy-blitz-may-2014.html" ><img id="academy-blitz-may-2014" src="img/album-covers/academy-blitz-may-2014.jpg" title="Academy Blitz May 2014"/></a>
    </td>

    <td>
      <a href="academy-blitz-october-2014.html" ><img id="academy-blitz-october-2014" src="img/album-covers/academy-blitz-october-2014.jpg" title="Academy Blitz October 2014"/></a>
    </td>

    <td>
      <a href="academy-blitz-november-2012.html" ><img id="academy-blitz-november-2012" src="img/album-covers/academy-blitz-november-2012.jpg" title="Academy Blitz November 2012"/></a>
    </td>

    <td>
      <a href="summer-camp-2014.html" ><img id="summer-camp-2014" src="img/album-covers/summer-camp-2014.jpg" title="Summer Camp 2014"/></a>
    </td>

    <td>
      <a href="academy-on-tour-tullamore-2015.html" ><img id="academy-on-tour-tullamore-2015" src="img/album-covers/academy-on-tour-tullamore-2015.jpg" title="Academy On Tour - Tullamore 2015"/></a>
    </td>


  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      Academy Blitz May 2014
    </td>

    <td>
      Academy Blitz October 2014
    </td>

    <td>
      Academy Blitz November 2012
    </td>

    <td>
      Summer Camp 2014
    </td>

    <td>
      Academy On Tour - Tullamore 2015
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      <a href="u18s-v-mullingar-2013.html" ><img id="u18s-v-mullingar-2013" src="img/album-covers/u18s-v-mullingar-2013.jpg" title="U18's V Mullingar 2013"/></a>
    </td>

    <td>
      <a href="u18s-league-win-2014.html" ><img id="u18s-league-win-2014" src="img/album-covers/u18s-league-win-2014.jpg" title="U18's League Win 2014"/></a>
    </td>

    <td>
      <a href="u12s-v-tullamore-2014.html" ><img id="u12s-v-tullamore-2014" src="img/album-covers/u12s-v-tullamore-2014.jpg" title="U12's V Tullamore 2014"/></a>
    </td>

    <td>
      <a href="u11-lions-semi-final-2015.html" ><img id="u11-lions-semi-final-2015" src="img/album-covers/u11-lions-semi-final-2015.jpg" title="U11 Lions Semi-Final 2015"/></a>
    </td>

    <td>
      <a href="easter-camp-2015.html" ><img id="easter-camp-2015" src="img/album-covers/easter-camp-2015.jpg" title="Easter Camp 2015"/></a>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      U18's v Mullingar 2013
    </td>

    <td>
      U18's League Win 2014
    </td>

    <td>
      U12's v Tullamore 2014
    </td>

    <td>
      U11 Lions Semi-Final 2015
    </td>

    <td>
      Easter Camp 2015
    </td>
  </tr>      
</table>
```

And my CSS:

```
#albums {width:70%;}

#albums img {opacity: 0.9;}

#albums img:hover {opacity:1.0;}

#albums td {text-align:center;padding-top:14px;padding-right:14px;padding-bottom:0px;padding-left:14px;}
```

Whenever I try to reduce the size, all other features fit to the screen size, but the gallery stays the same size, despite using the same code for the other features (width:%).

This is what it looks like full screen:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/n1rC5.jpg

And this is what it looks like when I reduce the window size:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/HYytn.jpg

Comment: In your HTML code where is `#imagegallery`?

Comment: in your css, img have a set width so it will no change if you resize. Is this the issue? Secondly maybe I missed it but I canot see an id="imagegallery" anywhere in your html

Comment: Just Add Below CSS:

 #imagegallery img {
  max-width:100%; 
 }
 .images{
  width:100%; 
 }

Comment: @SureshPonnukalai Apologies, I added the wrong CSS code. Edited now.

Comment: @keikoku92 Apologies, I added the wrong CSS code. Edited now.

Comment: you will have an issue because you set fixed size padding-top/right/left (btw you should changed it to padding: 14px 14px 0 14px;) so even with the resize it will keep them so your gallery will not change

Comment: @user3756181 Thanks, that seems to fix it somewhat. Seems I'm still having trouble with resizing fully as they stop resizing at a certain size. Must be down to the padding.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the images responsive

```
#albums img {
    width:100%;
    max-width:100%;
}
```

However the padding, text and the fact its a table will stop it from downsizing all the way.

Also semantically using a table in this way is quite bad. It looks like you're using it solely for layout purposes. You could achieve the same effect with a few divs and you'll have a lot more flexibility and be semantically correct.

Here's [a codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LVxxJv) with a better way of doing it. You would probably want to turn it into a 2 column or single column layout with a media query around 600px.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried changing it to divs but I couldn't figure out a way to get the album titles to sit exactly under the album images. Could you recommend a way of going about this?